# Windows Phone Emulator - Data from real device

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am developing a Windows Phone application which is tightly bound on the data which is stored on the phone.

My device has low screen dimensions (480 x 800), but I need to test my application on devices with higher screen dimensions, for which I am using windows phone emulators provided with the SDK.

Is there any easy way to make emulators use the data on my phone (i.e. SD card contents, for, for instance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do it from the `Additional Tools` from the `WP Emulator`.

Reference: [Accessing SD from Emulator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629629.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#SD_CARD)